# ExtJs5 - overriding native method defined inside ext-all-debug.js

Tags: firefox, extjs, migration, overriding, firebug

Suppose i want to **override** a function inside the native code provided by Sencha in the file **ext-all-debug.js**.

The function is defined inside the **Ext.util.Renderable**-class and has the name **cacheRefEls**.

The **overriding** should take place inside the **index.html** of the project to make it easier to maintain for future releases.

---

I have **already tried out** the override solutions proposed inside this thread:

[Steps to overriding Sencha ExtJS standard component functionality (Ext.tree.Panel & Ext.data.TreeStore as two examples)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249715/steps-to-overriding-sencha-extjs-standard-component-functionality-ext-tree-pane)

---

My index.html looks as follows:

```
<html>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.define('Myapp.view.Renderable', {
        override: 'Ext.util.Renderable',
        cacheRefEls: function(el) {
              console.log("in overider method");
             //my adapted version of it
        }   
    });
</script>
...
</html>
```

Unfortunately after accessing the **localhost:8080** over **Firefox-33** it is visible from the **Firebug-2-Console-log** that it still uses the native version of the function.

**What am i missing here?**

Comment: cacheRefEls is a private method and cannot be overridden. If you created your override successfully you should be seeing: `Ext.util.Renderable: Public method "cacheRefEls" conflicts with private framework method declared by Ext.util.Renderable`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In ExtJS 5, you need to move these methods to the `privates` configuration.

You should have seen the error:

> Public method "cacheRefEls" conflicts with private framework method declared by Ext.util.Renderable

You can still override the private method.  In your case, the solution would be:

```
Ext.define('Myapp.view.Renderable', {
    override: 'Ext.util.Renderable',
    privates: {
       cacheRefEls: function(el) {
          console.log("in overider method");
         //my adapted version of it
       }
    }   
});
```

Comment: not all overridden methods need to go within privates, only those that originally belong there like cacheRefEls. You would have to add statics if the method that you are trying to override belongs there.